# java + log4j : How to fix "No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies)"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, java, eclipse

Working with selenium + maven project in eclipse. I am facing below warnings:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for
> logger(org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I have tried

- Adding log4j.properties
- Corrected jdk version
- updated pom.xml file with accurate dependancy
- Ensure that those files are physically available and link in build with correct + valid path
- cleaned project in eclipse
- updated all maven dependancies

Anyone has experience and face, **please guide/suggest how those can be fixed?**

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j) out.

Comment: good to see your quick response. But I have tried those solutions already, No success yet !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied below solution steps -

1. **Remove Proxy**

   - Ensure your computer is not using any proxies, connect to open network
2. **Open terminal and hit below commands**:

   - rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/antlr
   - rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/aopalliance
   - rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/asm
3. **Remove/delete that particular dependent .JAR from library** folder
4. From terminal navigate to your project root folder and hit:

   - **mvn -U clean install**
5. Crosscheck once that dependent all .JAR are visible under .m2 folder. Sometime few of them may not get automatically downloaded, so if not seen pls add those manually

Finally - **I got everything working now :)**

Answer (score 1):

In Your Project, you have added log4j JAR but in your code you have not used any logs.
This Warning can be ignored.